# VBA Wildcards for number of characters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a file based on wildcards but it is not behaving as I expect. There are two files in a folder with similar names. The names are "abc_abc1234561_123456_123456" and "abc_abc1234561_123456_1234". The names are very similar but I always want to open the one with 6 digits after the third underscore.

```
Sub Compile_Results(tasklist As String)
    
    strFilePath = "\Documents\"
   
    'loop through files
    For i = 1 To 3
        'open each plate file
        sFound = Dir(strFilePath & "abc_" & tasklist & i & "_??????_??????.xls")
        If sFound <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open filename:=strFilePath & sFound
            MsgBox (sFound)
            Workbooks(sFound).Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The key part of the code is the search string `"abc_" & tasklist & i & "_??????_ ??????.xls"`. From my googling the 6 question marks should not be able to select the file with 4 digits. The variable `tasklist` is passed in by user input.

How can I open the file with 6 digits after the third underscore?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for everyone's help. Here is the code that worked.

```
Sub Compile_Results(tasklist As String)
    
    strFilePath = "\Documents"
    
    'loop through screen plates
    For i = 1 To 3
        'open each plate file
        sFound = Dir(strFilePath & "abc_" & tasklist & i & "_??????_??????.xls")
        
        Do While sFound <> ""
            sFound = Replace(sFound, ".xls", "")
            arr = Split(sFound, "_")
            If Len(arr(UBound(arr))) = 6 Then
                j = j + 1
                Workbooks.Open filename:=strFilePath & sFound & ".xls"
                
                'do stuff

                Workbooks(sFound & ".xls").Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If
            sFound = Dir()
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

This works but I am still not sure why the wildcards didn't.

Comment: Would these wildcards work a little better: `Dir(strFilePath & "abc_" & tasklist & i & "_*_######.xl*"`? What is the problem anyway? Does it pick 4 digit file or does not pick a file at all?

Comment: The current problem is that it selects the 4 digit file. When I use the # wildcard I get no results.

Comment: @VictorK I don't believe `Dir` supports the use of `#`.

Comment: I have been trying different things and when the file is renamed "abc.abc1234561.123456.123456" by replacing the "_" with "." and the search string ```"abc." & tasklist & i & ".??????.??????.xls"``` it selects the correct file. Is there something wrong with the _? I think it is what causes the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the length of the final part:

```
sFound = "abc_abc1234561_123456_123456.xls"


sFound = Replace(sFound, ".xls", "")
arr = Split(sFound, "_")
If Len(arr(UBound(arr))) = 6 Then
    '  here enter your Open coding
End If
```

Comment: I might be wrong here but wont that prevent it from selecting the incorrect (with 4 digits) file but it won't select the correct one either?

Comment: @MatthewEdmond  It will only select if the final part *(the part between the final underscore and the .xls)* is exactly 6 characters long.  If this is not what you want, then ignore my answer.

Comment: You are totally right. I did not understand that Dir could return more than one result. So this got me on the right track. I added a loop to go through the results of Dir.